# Find the logic in first 2 statements to give the answer for the third statement

Tags: pattern

There are 3 statements. This is a logical question, so you need to use the first two statements as an example to find the answer for the last statement.

> tea + rainbow = 9
>
> tree + hand = 8

pancake + solar system =?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This might be one that falls under “too broad”, but:

> Using (# of letters in Word 1) + (# of items in Word 2) - 1 should get you to an answer, however poorly defined it might be.

Examples:

> tea + rainbow = 3 letters in tea + 7 colours of the rainbow - 1 = 9 
>  tree + hand = 4 letters in tree + 5 digits on hand - 1 = 8 
>  pancake + solar system = 7 letters in pancake + 8 planets in solar system (sorry Pluto) - 1 = **14**.

So an answer could be

> Pancake + Solar System = 14.

Answer (score 5):

Since there are just two examples, and it's just mathematical/logical we can simply do this:

> 8.5 + 0.5*((#vowels in word 2) - (#vowels in word 1))

In your example, it's

> tea has 2 vowels
>  rainbow has 3 vowels
>  3 - 2 = 1
>  8.5 + 0.5 * 1 = 9
>
>  tree has 2 vowels
>  hand has 1 vowel
>  1 - 2 = -1
>  8.5 + 0.5 * -1 = 8

That means the answer to pancake + solar system is:

> 8.5 + 0.5 * (3 - 3) = 8.5

Of course this is a nonsense answer because we can utilise this way of reasoning with any number of examples, by using higher order functions.

Comment: Yep, this is the kind of alternate answer I was anticipating— great creativity! +1

Answer (score 3):

Another solution that works for the example is

> pancake + solar system = 16

Theory:

> #(characters in word 1) + #(characters in word 2) - #(letters used in both words)

Examples:

> tea + rainbow = 3 + 7 - 1 (because of a) = 9 
>  tree + hand = 4 + 4 = 8 (no letters shared) 
>  pancake + solar system = 7 + 11 - 2 (because of a and e) = 16

Comment: Nice one. Tons of these can be applied to this kind of question with few examples

Answer (score -1):

The number of different letters in the word pair

```
tea + rainbow = 9

tree + hand = 8
```

pancake + solar system = 13 (panckesolrytm)

Comment: tree + hand $\ne$ 8: there are two copies of the letter 'e'.

Comment: @SayedMohdAli Although poorly formatted (no spoiler tags), this answer was posted before 53RT's

Comment: @bg6471 yes, this one can also work if he tries to explain better and with proper formatting...